# How to reduce code with generics and probably reflection

Tags: java, generics, kotlin

I have DTO objects, then I need to sort the collection of objects dynamically, kind of like a database ORDER BY, but I do not have a database to actually make the queries do the actual work (I know, but it is what I have today...).

It seems to me that the StatusComparator and TypeComparator should be able to be re-written as fully generic and probably also make use of reflection so that I do not need to write one for each object in my API (I have three more for this service and it is getting really repetitive).

Once I understand the correct way to write this, I plan on extracting the Comparators out into their own library so that I may share the pattern with other divisions in my company to make their code easier to write.

This code is in Kotlin, so would really like to focus on that implementation as much as possible.

DTOs:

```java
@Table("type")
data class TypeObject(

    @get:NotNull
    @PrimaryKey
    @JsonProperty("id") val id: String,

    @get:NotNull
    @Column("type")
    @JsonProperty("type") val type: String,

    @Column("is_deleted")
    @JsonProperty("isDeleted") val isDeleted: Boolean? = null
)

@Table("status")
data class StatusObject(
    @get:NotNull
    @PrimaryKey
    @JsonProperty("id") val id: String,

    @get:NotNull
    @JsonProperty("status") val status: String,

    @Column("is_deleted")
    @JsonProperty("isDeleted") val isDeleted: Boolean? = null
)
```

Comparatoes:

```java
@Component
class StatusComparator<T : StatusObject> {
    fun buildComparator(
        field: String,
        asc: Boolean
    ): Comparator<T> {
        return if (asc) {
            compareBy {
                getField(field, it)
            }
        } else {
            compareByDescending {
                getField(field, it)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun getField(
        field: String,
        it: StatusObject
    ): Comparable<*>? {
        return when (field.toLowerCase()) {
            "id" -> it.id
            "status" -> it.status
            else -> it.isDeleted
        }
    }
}

@Component
class TypeComparator<T : TypeObject> {
    fun buildComparator(
        field: String,
        asc: Boolean
    ): Comparator<T> {
        return if (asc) {
            compareBy {
                getField(field, it)
            }
        } else {
            compareByDescending {
                getField(field, it)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun getField(
        field: String,
        it: TypeObject
    ): Comparable<*>? {
        return when (field.toLowerCase()) {
            "id" -> it.id
            "type" -> it.type
            else -> it.isDeleted
        }
    }
}
```

Sample usage in my Type Service:

```java
@Service
class TypeApiServiceImpl(
    private val repo: TypeRepository,
    private val sortListBuilder: SortListBuilder,
    private val customComparator: TypeComparator<TypeObject>
) : TypeApiService {

    override fun get(
        sort: String,
        filterId: UUID,
        filterType: String,
        filterIsDeleted: Boolean
    ): Mono<DocumentTierModels> {
        return if (filterId != UUID.fromString("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")) {
            this.getTypeById(filterId)
        } else {
            val objects = this.getTypeByFilter(filterType, filterIsDeleted)

            if (sort != "null") {
                this.getSortedTypes(sort, objects)
            } else {
                TypesModels(objects, MetaModel(null, listOf())).toMono()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun sortObject(
        objects: List<TypeObject>,
        sortItems: List<String>
    ): List<TypeObject> {
        when (sortItems.count()) {
            1 -> {
                val fieldAndDirection1 = sortItems[0].split(',')

                return objects
                    .sortedWith(customComparator.buildComparator(fieldAndDirection1[0], fieldAndDirection1[1] == "asc"))
            }
            2 -> {
                val fieldAndDirection1 = sortItems[0].split(',')
                val fieldAndDirection2 = sortItems[1].split(',')

                return objects
                    .sortedWith(
                        customComparator.buildComparator(fieldAndDirection1[0], fieldAndDirection1[1] == "asc")
                            .then(customComparator.buildComparator(fieldAndDirection2[0], fieldAndDirection2[1] == "asc"))
                    )
            }
            3 -> {
                val fieldAndDirection1 = sortItems[0].split(',')
                val fieldAndDirection2 = sortItems[1].split(',')
                val fieldAndDirection3 = sortItems[2].split(',')

                return objects
                    .sortedWith(
                        customComparator.buildComparator(fieldAndDirection1[0], fieldAndDirection1[1] == "asc")
                            .then(customComparator.buildComparator(fieldAndDirection2[0], fieldAndDirection2[1] == "asc"))
                            .then(customComparator.buildComparator(fieldAndDirection3[0], fieldAndDirection3[1] == "asc"))
                    )
            }
            else -> {
                return objects
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample usage in my Status Service:

```java
@Service
class StatusesApiServiceImpl(
    private val repo: StatusRepository,
    private val sortListBuilder: SortListBuilder,
    private val customComparator: StatusComparator<StatusObject>
) : StatusesApiService {

    override fun get(
        sort: String,
        filterId: UUID,
        filterStatus: String,
        filterIsDeleted: Boolean
    ): Mono<StatusModels> {
        return if (filterId != UUID.fromString("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")) {
            this.getStatusById(filterId)
        } else {
            val objects = this.getStatusByFilter(filterStatus, filterIsDeleted)

            if (sort != "null") {
                this.getSortedStatuses(sort, objects)
            } else {
                StatusModels(objects, MetaModel(null, listOf())).toMono()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun getSortedStatuses(
        sort: String,
        objects: List<StatusObject>
    ): Mono<StatusModels> {
        var objects1 = objects
        var sortList: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
        val sortItems = sortListBuilder.getSortItems(sort)

        if (sortItems != null) {
            sortList = sortListBuilder.buildSortList(sortItems)
            objects1 = this.sortObject(objects1, sortItems)
        }

        val meta = MetaModel(null, sortList)

        return StatusModels(objects1, meta).toMono()
    }

    private fun sortObject(
        objects: List<StatusObject>,
        sortItems: List<String>
    ): List<StatusObject> {
        when (sortItems.count()) {
            1 -> {
                val fieldAndDirection1 = sortItems[0].split(',')

                return objects
                    .sortedWith(customComparator.buildComparator(fieldAndDirection1[0], fieldAndDirection1[1] == "asc"))
            }
            2 -> {

                val fieldAndDirection1 = sortItems[0].split(',')
                val fieldAndDirection2 = sortItems[1].split(',')

                return objects
                    .sortedWith(customComparator.buildComparator(fieldAndDirection1[0], fieldAndDirection1[1] == "asc")
                        .then(customComparator.buildComparator(fieldAndDirection2[0], fieldAndDirection2[1] == "asc")))
            }
            3 -> {
                val fieldAndDirection1 = sortItems[0].split(',')
                val fieldAndDirection2 = sortItems[1].split(',')
                val fieldAndDirection3 = sortItems[2].split(',')

                return objects
                    .sortedWith(customComparator.buildComparator(fieldAndDirection1[0], fieldAndDirection1[1] == "asc")
                        .then(customComparator.buildComparator(fieldAndDirection2[0], fieldAndDirection2[1] == "asc"))
                        .then(customComparator.buildComparator(fieldAndDirection3[0], fieldAndDirection3[1] == "asc")))
            }
            else -> {
                return objects
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also now see in my question that I may also be able to apply this pattern to my actual services as well, but let's take this one step at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Reflection

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
fun <T : Any> KClass<T>.compareByProperty(propName: String, asc: Boolean = true): Comparator<T> {
    val property = declaredMemberProperties.first { it.name == propName }
    val getter = property::get as (T) -> Comparable<*>

    if (asc) {
        return compareBy(getter)
    }
    return compareByDescending(getter)
}
```

The first extension function `compareByProperty` uses reflection to lookup the property by name and then extract the getter of the property as a selector of `Conparable`

Then depending on the `asc` parameter the `getter` is transformed to a `Comparator` of the generic type with the standard function [`compareBy` and `compareByDescending`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.comparisons/index.html):

#### Helper to combine

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> Comparator<T>.thenByProperty(propName: String, asc: Boolean = true) =
    then(T::class.compareByProperty(propName, asc))
```

The second extension function allows to combine `Comparator`s:

#### Usage

```
fun main() {
    val typeObjects = listOf(...)
    val comparator = TypeObject::class.compareByProperty("id")
        .thenByProperty("type", asc = false)

    val sortedTypes = typeObjects.sortedWith(comparator)
}
```

The usage looks like in this example main function. Access the `KClass` object via `::`.
Then call the first extension function and use the second extension function to combine `Comparable`s:

Comment: this is a beautifully simple and elegant solution. Very easy to understand and implement. Thank you!